# how can I filter out same commands in tcsh history

Tags: linux, shell, history, tcsh

I am using tcsh. But annoyed by same command stored in history file. I have to use multiple times of up arrow to bypass the same command, very inconvenient.
Can anyone give some help to solve this inconvenience.

Comment: Bash has `erasedups`.

Comment: @zhaoyang : I think this question is better asked at [superuser](https://superuser.com/), because it is related to configuring your tcsh and not to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `histdup` setting for this; from `tcsh(1)`:

```
   histdup (+)
           Controls handling of duplicate entries in the history list.  If
           set to `all' only unique history events are entered in the
           history list.  If set to `prev' and the last history event is
           the same as the current command, then the current command is
           not entered in the history.  If set to `erase' and the same
           event is found in the history list, that old event gets erased
           and the current one gets inserted.  Note that the `prev' and
           `all' options renumber history events so there are no gaps.
```

Comment: thanks. I use set histdup=prev perfectly solve my problem.